# Is there any way to search in filetypes not recognized by ack?

Tags: ack

You can use `ack --js` to search only in js files. But what if the file type I want to search for is not currently recognized by ack? Any way to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a new type by adding something like:

```
--type-set=eiffel=.e,.eiffel
```

...to your `~/.ackrc` file. You could also use the `-a` command-line option that searches (nearly) all files.

Comment: And it doesn't have to be in your ~/.ackrc.  It can also go in ACK_OPTIONS.