# Ack: Using --add-type with v. 2.04

Tags: ack, add-type

How do I add a new filetype to ack, with version 2.04 (ack-2.04-single-file). I am using the following command ([Is there any way to search in filetypes not recognized by ack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734301/is-there-any-way-to-search-in-filetypes-not-recognized-by-ack)), but I receive an error.

```
$ ack --type-set=input=.i
ack-2.04-single-file: No regular expression found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following does what I wanted:

```
--type-add=input:ext:i
```

I found the answer by creating a .ackrc file with:

```
ack --create-ackrc
```

Comment: I'm using --type-add=zcml:ext:zcml --type=zcml only works on the command line, not the .ackrc file. Not sure why